# Number pattern printing in c

Tags: c

I'm newbie to programming. So as an exercise, I'm trying to print a number pattern like below.

```
0
10
210
3210
43210
```

I tried the code below.

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 void main()
 {
    int i ,j,n=5;
    for(i=0;i<=n;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j>=i;j--)
        {
           printf("%d",i);
        }
        printf("\n");
     }
}
```

The output am getting after running the code above is:-

```
10
10
10
10
10
```

Am just stuck. Not able to solve this question. Can anyone help me please?

Comment: The `j` loop is wrong.

Comment: learn to use your debugger. If the environment you are using doesnt have a debugger (very rare) then use a different environment.

Comment: hey paul i'd like to thank you for answering the question .can you help me come up with the correct j loop?

Comment: Loop `i` is incorrect: runs as `0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5` hence total 6 lines.
Loop `j` is incorrect: starts from 0 and should be greater than or equals to `i` (`i` is always greater than or equals to 0).
Please check these two and it should work.

Comment: `void main()` is ancient. Use `int main(void)` instead.

Comment: breaking the problem into several smaller parts is always a good idea: https://ideone.com/URf3IX

Answer (score 0):

There are two loops.
The first loop control the line number with range as [0,N).
The second loop control the character sequences per line. Each line print out [Line_Number + 1] digital numbers. The sequence has a pattern as [Line_Number - Column_Number].

The example code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main() {
  int i, j, n = 5;
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < (i + 1); j++) {
      printf("%d", (i - j));
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
}
```

Build and run:

```
gcc test.c
./a.out
```

The output:

```
0
10
210
3210
43210
```

Answer (score 0):

You have done a simple mistake for the `inner loop-j`. Make sure that your outer loop `i-loop` refers to the number of lines and your printing as `printf("%d",i);` defines how many lines you want.

```
#include<stdio.h> 
void main() 
{ 
    int i ,j,n=5; 
    for(i=0;i<n;i++) 
    {
        for(j=i;j>=0;j--) 
        {
            printf("%d",j);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Then the output will be:

```
0
10
210
3210
43210
```

Answer (score -2):

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 void main()
 { 
 int i ,j,n=5,t[n];
   for(i=0;i<n;i++)
     {
        t[i]=i;
        for(j=i;j>=0;j--)
           {
              printf("%d",t[j]);                  
           } 
        printf("\n");
     }
```

try this...

Comment: can you explain how you did it?

Comment: used an array with n values, storing the numbers accordingly and reverse printing the array for every iteration